# Allow user to download file created via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, phpword

I'm using PHPWord to generate MS word documents in php. It works fine and i can create a file and store it on my server via an ajax request, but after its created i need to allow the user to download it.

There has to be someway i can serialize the file and pass it back in the ajax response then queue it for download in javascript? I could use any advice on how to do this with a file

after the file is created, i tried in php:

```
 $wordFile = file_get_contents('helloWorld2018.docx');
```

and then tried returning that, but ofcourse i got an error as i tried to convert it as a JSON variable. Is there someway i could serialize this, pass it via json, then queue it for download? I'm using Jquery and Codeigniter btw

thanks

Comment: Force a new tab that loads the file as a download. AJAX isn't for this type thing.

Comment: When they click on the link, you can just send the file to the client without using ajax to get the file content, convert it into the file, and download it.

Comment: On the success callback you can trigger the download using location.href pointing to the generated file. Still I wouldn't use ajax for doing this.

Comment: Tip: use `readfile` instead of `file_get_contents`

Comment: ok uhm 4 different answers, and none of them saying how to do it. I dont want to open a different tab i'd really like the download to just start. for example i can do a pdf in javascript then the user downloads the file. unfortunately the library i found to do word documents only works in php. When they click the download button i want it to start without a new tab if possible. there has to be a way to serialize and unserialize files??? Code examples would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well this is what I found. Juan had the correct response but gets a massive downvote for not explaining how that is done, or explaining that window.location won't actually redirect the user if its pointing to a file, it just queues the download, which is perfect

I use Codeigniter, so after the file is created, i have this controller called 'Download'

```
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=hellowWorld2018.docx");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");    
    readfile("helloWorld2018.docx");
```

Then in the ajax success function i just say window.location = 'download' and it downloads the file.

Still havent figured out how i'm going to set the headers and readfile command dynamically yet but that should be relatively easy. thanks, G